# How to convert 'io.BufferedWriter' to 'Dataframe' - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, bufferedwriter

I am downloading files from One Drive with the following piece of code:

```py
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('\n> Response Success')

    with open('Book2.xlsx', 'wb') as File:
        File.write(response.content)
        
        print('\n> File Downloaded')
else:
    print('\n> Failed:', response.status_code)
    print(response.content)
```

The code is from:[This post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61695577/not-able-to-download-files-from-inside-folder-onedrive-microsoft-graph-python)

The "File" is coming from One Drive with the use of the following code:

```py
import sys, os, time, requests
import pandas as pd
import urllib.parse

OneDrive_FilePath = 'Book2.xlsx'

OneDrive_FileURL = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/' + OneDrive_FilePath + ':/content'
OneDrive_FileURL = urllib.parse.quote(OneDrive_FileURL, safe=':/')
print(OneDrive_FileURL)

Client_Id = 'XXXX'
Tenant_Id = 'YYYYY'
Refresh_Token_First = 'ZZZZZ'

PostStr = {'grant_type': 'refresh_token', 'client_id': Client_Id, 'refresh_token': Refresh_Token_First}

Token_Response = requests.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + Tenant_Id + '/oauth2/v2.0/token', data=PostStr)

Access_Token = Token_Response.json()['access_token']
New_Refresh_Token = Token_Response.json()['refresh_token']

if Access_Token is None or New_Refresh_Token is None:
    print('\n> Failed: Access_Token NOT Retrieved')
    sys.exit()

Response = requests.get(OneDrive_FileURL, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Access_Token})
```

The "File" which is getting downloaded is in the form of "io.BufferedWriter". I want to actually load the "File" as a data frame so that I can do certain operations on that and upload it to AWS.

How can I do that, please help.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a URL that contains this kind of file, so that one can experiment with it?

Comment: Also, please include the code that actually creates 'File'.

Comment: @Roy2012 - I have edited the post and added the code used for accessing the "File" from One drive. Hope this helps and this is the only code I am using for downloading the "File".

Comment: I don't have the access tokens, so I can't run your code. If I understand correctly, 'File' is just an Excel file that you'd like to read into a dataframe? Is that what the question is about?

Comment: @Roy2012 - Yes it is an Excel file in One Drive, But when the file is accessed the way it is accessed right now, it changes to a type - "io.BufferedWriter". I would like to change that to the dataframe or at the first place read it as dataframe. Thanks

Comment: You're saving it to disk eventually. Why can't you just open it as an excel with pandas?

Comment: @Roy2012- I am trying to establish One Drive to AWS S3 sync. I am not supposed to actually load things locally on my desktop and then create a data frame and upload it to S3. I want to do it straight.

Comment: So the type of File is probably irrelevant. What's the type of "response.content"? I guess it's bytes or string?

Comment: @Roy2012 - yes its Bytes

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Many Thanks. Sorted !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the type of `File` is mostly irrelevant. All you need to do is read the excel directly from the response, as in :

```
url = "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962"
res = requests.get(url)
pd.read_excel(res.content)
```

The last statement produces a regular pandas dataframe. You can use that however you want.