# Delete files from OneDrive after copy via ADF

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I do the following:
I copy data from OneDrive to Datalake. For this I have built HTTP linked service, HTTP dataset and pipelines in ADF. Linked service and dataset also for Datalake.

Copy works fine.

But I also want the data in OneDrive to be deleted automatically after copying.

Is there a way to delete the data in Onedrive?

Comment: Although there is no direct way to delete data in OneDrive from ADF, can you share your existing setup how you are copying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there is a Delete activity available now in ADF it has a limited scope. See [Supported data stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/delete-activity#supported-data-stores)

So if you are able to get the files from OneDrive using HTTP service, I would suggest you try this REST API doc [Delete a DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_delete?view=odsp-graph-online) and use REST linked service to delete corresponding files after copy activity is successful.

With this you can Delete a DriveItem by using its ID or path.

Comment: From my repro and other docs getting onedrive files using adf is not supported through any explicit connectors. You would have to use REST API and web activity to try make a download request. See, [Download the contents of a DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content?view=odsp-graph-online)

Comment: Or use a function app with python code as an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58259492/15969417) and for [Downloading a file in another format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content_format?view=odsp-graph-online)

Comment: Haven't tried yet though, what error do you see ? try checking this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/errors?view=odsp-graph-online