# upload & download files from OneDrive with Python, do I need an Azure account?

Tags: python, azure, onedrive

I have some files in my personal OneDrive account. I want to access some of these files with Python, make some updates & then upload back to OneDrive.

I have seen a few examples on here & some other sites, which seem to make sense. My question though is in order to download files & upload files to OneDrive programmatically whether I need a Azure account? My understanding is that I need this for the authentication part. I would happily create an Azure account however I see you have to pay. There is a free 12 month option but for what I would like to do, 12 months is not long enough.

Comment: Have you tried with `Delegated permission(personal Microsoft account)` of [Microsoft Graph REST AP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)? References: [OneDrive API and Azure Active Directory setup to upload as personal account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66787193/onedrive-api-and-azure-active-directory-setup-to-upload-as-personal-account?rq=1)  and [Download files from personal OneDrive using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58171733/download-files-from-personal-onedrive-using-python)

Comment: **I think you will still need an Azure account as MS Graph uses AAD.**
 "Microsoft Graph uses Azure Active Directory to authenticate accounts and authorize applications. Using the v2.0 endpoint your application can sign in consumer users with Microsoft accounts and work/school users with Azure Active Directory accounts with a single authentication flow. " Reference: [Authorizing your app to access OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/authentication?view=odsp-graph-online#microsoft-graph-onedrive-and-sharepoint-online)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT thanks for the above, just going through the links now & will check delegated permissions. Tend to agree though looks like I will need to get an Azure account and pay unless I can find another cloud provider

Answer (score 1):

> My question though is in order to download files & upload
> files to OneDrive programmatically whether I need a Azure account?

**Azure account is not mandatory when you need to access and read/write files from OneDrive.**

With `python-onedrive` module, you can access personal OneDrive account.

To install, run: `pip install python-onedrive`

Refer this [OneDrive SDK for Python](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python) GitHub repository to implement the same.

Comment: This library is deprecated per PyPi: https://pypi.org/project/onedrivesdk/